# MySQL Log to show users

Tags: mysql, users, user-accounts

I have a MySQL server running with about 50 users. I am looking for a way to tell which users are still actively accessing the server, which accounts are used.

I already thought about grep-ping binary logs over a longer period, but they do not contain this information.
I also though about `show processlist` which is done by this. But polling a busy server (300 queries per second) seems useless.

How can I achieve this? Server is MySQL 4.1 on Debian 4.0.

Comment: First hit on google for `mysql show active users` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216502/list-logged-in-mysql-users

Comment: Thanks @lain so far, I edited my question to give more input which shows that your point is good but not may fail in my situation.